# uploading file in php to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, file, mysqli

I am trying to upload a file using a form and then grab that cvs file and insert its contents into mysql table. When I submit the form it does tells me that it failed everytime, and I am not sure why. Here is my form.

```
<form action="Scripts/upload-instructions.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
```

the php file that is supposed to enter the data into the database does not upload the data. I think it has something to do with the post of file input name from the form. I am new to uploading files to mysql and I am trying to get the sql to parse the file instead of the php itself. Here is my upload-instructions.php file

```
require("connection.php");

    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$query = "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE instructions
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (route_name,stop_sequence_number,stop_location_id,stop_action,stop_arrival_time,stop_departure_time,time_zone);
    ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)
    or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if ($result === false) { echo 'Query Fail'; }
if ($result === 0) { echo 'No update'; }
if ($result > 0) { echo 'Success'; }
```

I am getting an array to string conversion error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `$file = $_FILES['file'];` isn't enough. Read up on files http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: This won't help you after `echo 'Query Fail';` should there be a syntax error. Use `or die(mysqli_error($conn))`  to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: alright i used the die statement that helped and i added the tmp_name to the file but now it just tells me this error Can't find file 'C:xampp mpphpDD9D.tmp'. thats not the name of the or the tmp name why is it changing it?

Comment: Try `$file = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` since slashes are being stripped and need to be escaped. I saw a similar question with the same problem. Check to see if that tmp folder can be written to also.

Comment: Awesome that worked! I thought i tried that before I must have typed it in wrong. Thank you for your help I definately need to brush up my file uploading in php starting to learn this on my own is really confusing.

Comment: Great Alex, glad to hear it and you're welcome. Would you like me to post it as an answer for future visitors?

Comment: yes please that was the problem I didnt know i needed the addslashes function. I gave you the upvote for the correct answer also.

Comment: It has been done Alex, *cheers*.

Comment: I noticed though that you edited your question with my fix. I had to do a rollback to your 2nd revision. People will see the question and the answer I gave and ask themselves *"why the answer, `addslashes()` is in there."*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incoming file requires it to be escaped using `addslashes()` which is why the `\` is missing from your `Can't find file 'C:xampp mpphpDD9D.tmp'` and not being moved to the temp folder properly.

```
$file = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Since slashes are being stripped and need to be escaped.

Plus, as noted in your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31908027/1

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
```

isn't enough.

It requires `['tmp_name']` to be added for the array; hence the array to string conversion error.

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Sidenote:

This won't help you after `echo 'Query Fail';` should there be a syntax error. Use `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php